# Triple integrals converting between different coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Convert the following triple integral from rectangular coordinates to both cylindrical and spherical coordinates and evaluate the simplest iterated integral:
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_1^{1+\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}}x\,dz\,dy\,dx$$
I have converted to both polar and cylindrical but when evaluating i think i must have done the conversion wrong because it seems too complicated for the level we are at to evaluate. Are these conversions correct?

Cylindrical
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1+\sqrt{1-r^2}}r\cos\theta\cdot r\,dz\,d\theta\,dr$$
Spherical
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\rho\sin\varphi\cdot\rho^2\sin\varphi\,d\varphi\,d\theta\,d\rho$$

Comment: Your coordinate transform into spherical coordinates is wrong. You're missing a cosine.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. We have $$z=1+\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$ $$z=1$$ which defines this region

[image]

Cylindrical coordinate transform as follows. We'll set the bounds z first, then r and theta. Using the arrow and shadow method, we draw arrows from $z=-\infty$ to $z=\infty$ and see that the $z$ bounds are the same as rectangular coordinates

[image]

Now shine a light from $z=-\infty$ and $z=\infty$ to see what we get on the $x-y$ plane. This is just this unit circle

[image]

Your cylindrical conversion is correct.

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{1+\sqrt{1-r^2}}(r\cos(\theta))\cdot r\text{ d}z\text{ d}r\text{ d}\theta$$

---

Spherical coordinates time. We'll do rho, theta, phi. I'm not sure what you did with this substitution, but you substituted $x$ very wrong in your attempt.

Now since everything is shifted up $1$, this may pose some form of problem because we must be able to define a spherical function that fits this top portion. Instead of doing regular spherical coordinates, we'll use *modified spherical coordinates* for this particular problem. To wit, instead of $$x=\rho\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),\quad y=\rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\quad z=\rho\cos(\phi)$$
we'll do this change of coordinates
$$x=\rho\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),\quad y=\rho\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\quad z=\rho\cos(\phi)+1$$
this keeps the jacobian the same(since adding the constant to one part of the transformation does not change the jacobian  matrix nor the jacobian determinant), while shifting our entire coordinate system upwards such that the center of our previously elevated sphere is now at our origin.

This is just standard bounds, as you have found. We have

[image]

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (\rho\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi))\cdot\rho^2\sin(\phi) \text{ d}\rho\text{ d}\theta\text{ d}\phi$$

---

Numerical verification shows that all integrals are equal to zero.

Comment: Ah thanks looks like i forgot to add in cos() when subbing in for x. Is your sin() meant to be sin()??

Comment: @GbBlues oh wait yep my bad